# check to see if a view exists from a layout inflater befor adding another one

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

In my android project, I am dynamically adding forms to my linear layout and then destroying them when I am done with a button. However, When I click the "add button" It infinitely adds more forms although I want only one at a time. How can i chec if my linearLayout "accounts" has been added to the view or if it exists in the view at the time? This is the code to add the view. How can I check to see if the view already exists before I add the view?

```
  public void showForm(String form){
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater    
          =(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forms, null);
        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.accounts);
        l.addView(item);
   }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Option #1: Use `boolean accountsAdded=false;`, setting it to `true` when needed

Option #2: Use `l.findViewById(R.id.accounts)` and see if that returns `null`

BTW, you will crash if the root widget of `R.layout.forms` is not the `R.id.accounts` `View`, so please add `view`, not `item`, to `l` via `addView()`.

Comment: awesome, will that add the subviews as well if I add it that way?

Comment: @Dnaso: Yes. The method really should be named `addViewHierarchy()`, but perhaps that was too much typing. :-)

Comment: one quick question. is it possible to take just a part of a layout say i have a few widgets can I put them in one layout and just take a chunk of it as i need it.. IE special forms or should i create separate XML items for each? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Dnaso: I would use separate XML layouts for each, personally. You're welcome to play around with removing and adding views. The big thing is that you cannot add a view when that view already has a parent, so you will be removing from old locations and moving to new ones.

Answer (score 4):

You can check from ViewGroup indexOfChild(View view) method if the child is exist or not. it returns a positive integer representing the position of the view in the group, or -1 if the view does not exist in the group

```
ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) getWindow().peekDecorView();
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View myView= li.inflate(R.layout.recorder, null);
if(rootLayout.indexOfChild(myView) == -1)
    rootLayout.addView(myView);
```

Comment: I found the indexOfChild function helpful