# Conditional code for different xml version folder (NavigationView)

Tags: android, android-studio

My App is made to work from API 22 to 28, There is a NavigationView on it and is not working for API 22, so I made a folder for a different xml file for this version with no NavigationView, so I have these folders:

```
res/layout/activity_layout.xml
res/layout-v22/activity_layout.xml
res/layout-v23/activity_layout.xml
```

I want to addapt my code to know if I am using a layout-v22/ folder and don't build the NavigationView, I made something like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT!=22){
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
}
```

but I see an error because R.id.nav_view is not found (Cannot resolve symbol 'nav_view').

Another attempt was to check if the resource exists:

```
if(getResources().getIdentifier("nav_view","layout",getPackageName())!=0){
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
}
```

But I still getting the same error:

[image]

How can I write a condition to tell Android Studio I want to use this resource if exists only?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the returned value from `getIdentifier` so you don't need to accees the generated R file:

```
int navViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("nav_view", "id", getPackageName());
if(navViewId != 0){
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(navViewId);
}
```

Changed the second parameter from "layout" to "id".

Also I can see that you are trying to access `navigationView` after your if clause so next problem will be null pointer exception so take care of that too.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I wasn't able to fix it until now, I found an easier way to check if the view exists:

```
navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
if(navigationView!=null){
    // do something
}
```

I found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20432875/2966583

---

**Edited**

The previous solution is giving me a crash with NullPointerException message on Android 5.1 devices on the `findViewById` line.

I will try adding vilpe89 answer and mix both answers this way:

```
    int navViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("nav_view", "id", getPackageName());
    if(navViewId != 0){
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if(navigationView != null){
            // do something
        }
    }
```

*(This answer is a work in progress...)*